# How to change the defaults value for ObjectStoreModel in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using Dojo `ObjectStoreModel` for a dijit/Tree widget.
I need to configure `ObjectStoreModel` to use property named `parent_id` instead of the default `parent` in order to match my data structure.

Any idea how to set this configuration?

```
   var data = [
      {
        id: 'world',
        name: 'The earth',
        type: 'planet',
        population: '6 billion'
      },
      {
        id: 'EG',
        name: 'Egypt',
        type: 'country',
        parent_id: 'AF' // does not work if property is called parent_id, only parent by default
      },
      {
        id: 'Nairobi',
        name: 'Nairobi',
        type: 'city',
        parent_id: 'KE'
      },
      {
        id: 'Mombasa',
        name: 'Mombasa',
        type: 'city',
        parent_id: 'KE'
      },
      {
        id: 'SD',
        name: 'Sudan',
        type: 'country',
        parent_id: 'AF'
      },

    ];


            var myStore = new Memory({
                data: data,
                getChildren: function (object) {
                    return this.query({ parent: object.id });
                }
            });

            // Create the model
            var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
                store: myStore,
                query: { id: '0' }
            });


            // Create the Tree.
            var tree = new Tree({
                model: myModel
            });
            tree.placeAt(this.domNode);
            tree.startup();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel.html

Stating: `The dojo.store must implement it’s own getChildren() method.`

So with this edit script works fine.

```
var myStore = new Memory({
                data: data,
                getChildren: function (object) {
                    return this.query({ parent_id: object.id });
                }
            });
```